# Write zeros to file blocks

Tags: python, file-io

I'm attempting to identify the blocks that are tied to a specific file and write zeros to them. I've found several methods that do this to the free space on a disk, but so far I haven't found any slid suggestions for doing the following:

- identify the blocks for a file
- Write zeros to those blocks.

The purpose of this is for a virtualized system. This system has the ability to dedupe blocks that are identified as being the same. This is used to reduce space used by the guest OSes on the drive.

Currently this is being done using `dd` to write zeros to the free space on the drive. However this has the side effect on VMWare systems to cause the guest OS drive to use the entire disk space it has been allocated as from that point on the system things all the bytes have been written to.

Comment: I don't know - this looks horribly low-level to me; not really what a very high-level language like Python appears suitable for. I would be very surprised if native Python allowed that kind of access to the hardware.

Comment: Bring your scuba gear and dive into the deep C.

Comment: I was afraid that would end up being the consensus. Could someone please post for the final answer towards that end so I can accept and close the question?

Comment: Just a wild thought: could [mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) be an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing code that can safely modify even an unmounted filesystem will require significant effort. It is to be avoided unless there is no other option.

You basically have two choices to make modifying the filesystem easy:

- Run python *in* the virtual environment.
- Mount the virtualized filesystem on the host. Most UNIX-like systems can do that, e.g. with the help of [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) (which support a [lot of filesystem types](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems)) and [loop devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device).

This way you can use the (guest or host) OS's filesystem code instead of having to roll your own. :-) If you can use one of those options, the code fragment listed below will fill a file with zeroes:

```
import os

def overwrite(f):
    """Overwrite a file with zeroes.

    Arguments:
    f -- name of the file
    """
    stat = os.stat(f)
    with open(f, 'r+') as of:
        of.write('\0' * stat.st_size)
        of.flush()
```

Comment: That looks to do exactly what I needed.